# Image is not in ImageButton asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, imagebutton

I use ListView in asp.net. I get data from provider table. According providerId image is stored in same folder(like `1.jpg,2.jpg`).
I want to display image according to providerID.
But Image is not showing. but when i use simple html img control then image is showing.
What should i do for show image in ImageButton.

```
<asp:ListView DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" ItemPlaceholderID="dd" ID="ddlprovider" 
runat="server">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="dd" runat="server"/>
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ProviderID") %>.jpg' ID="imgButton" />//Not work
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProviderID") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="FetchAll" 
        TypeName="mogile.MidTier.DAL.ProviderController" UpdateMethod="Update">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: can you provide more code? seems like the bit you have posted is incomplete.

Comment: What is the generated path for that image? Do a 'view source' on the page in the browser. How does that differ from your simple html? That might give you some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put code breaks in an attribute with a string at the end like that.

Try changing the line of code to:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.format("{0}.jpg", Eval("ProviderID")) %>' ID="imgButton" />
```

EDIT:
If you wish to display a default image if this one doesn't exist you'll need to modify the code to:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageURL(Eval("ProviderID")) %>' ID="imgButton" />

Function GetImageURL(ProviderID as Integer) as String
    Dim ImageFileName as string = string.format("[image path here]/{0}", ProviderID)
    If Not File.Exists(server.mappath(imagefilename)) then imagefilename = "[default image path here]
    Return ImageFileName
End Function
```

Comment: you can put the format in eval: <%# Eval("ProviderID", "{0}.jpg") %>

Comment: Yeah thats just a short hand way I believe? Either way, I think the page is actually rendering "<%#Eval("ProviderID") %>.jpg", which is obviously not a real file path

Comment: please also help if image is not found according providerid then how i use default image.

Comment: Then you would need to do something in your code behind like: If Not File.Exists(....) Then imgButton.ImageUrl = "defaultimage.jpg"

Comment: @Curt, yes, mine was just a hint

Comment: thanks all.onof your code work. But if image are store some folder(AppResources\providerImage) then **ImageUrl='AppResources\providerImage\<%# Eval("ProviderID", "{0}.jpg") %>'** then it not work. how the way to do this.

Comment: thanks onof i did **ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProviderID", "~/AppResources/providerImage/{0}.jpg") %>'** please help if image not found in following path then i want display default image

Comment: thanks curt. but where i write this code. this is i think vb code. how i use this.

Comment: thanks curt. But where i write this code. I write this code in <body> tag but this give error getImageURL not found. please again help.

Comment: The Function will need to be put in your pages code behind. That's a .vb file for VB.NET, or .cs file for C# (code will have to be converted if C#)